# Database preview is not supported for this scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asynchronous

I recently started playing around with the Publish functionality in Visual Studio for web applications. I'm running a LocalDB instance on my PC that I would like to sync with my host.

However, when I get to the Preview tab (the last step in the publishing wizard) page, it says that a preview could not be generated due to the "scenario" chosen.

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

**Edit** It should be noted that I am using a LocalDB instance. Could that be why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be caused by me specifying the connection strings to use programmatically, and not in my web.config file. After adding them there and making a transformation web.config file, it worked just fine.